# Creating a specific list in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I want to write a function to write a list that, for example, for the code below

> likes('john', 'soccer')
>
> likes('mary', 'football')
>
> likes('eric', 'soccer')

So the function I want to write would be like

> whoLikes('soccer', list)

And the list would be ('john', 'eric')

Should I use recursion to do this? How?

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the built-in predicate `setof/3`:

```
likes(messi,soccer).
likes(ronaldo,soccer).
likes(jordan,basketball).

whoLikesSoccer(F):- setof(X,likes(X,soccer),F).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?- whoLikesSoccer(X).
   X=[messi,ronaldo].
   false
```